# Meaning of the verb "scale" in the context of weightlifting

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/jv31A4Ab4nA). It is at around 1 minute and 32 second.

> We cannot get around overhead pressing, but we want to make sure even when we do that, we do it properly and we actually have a way we can **scale** the weights when we do it.

Does *scale* mean the to be able to press the weight all the way up?

Comment: Possibly related to the "Borg Scale".  Rating of Perceived Exertion (RPE): Also known as the Borg Scale. RPE is a subjective (determined by you the lifter) measurement of how hard an exercise feels. The Scale goes from 0-10. For most barbell training, your sets of an exercise should be somewhere between RPE 6 and 10.  https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/the-ultimate-glossary-of-strength-and-conditioning-terms/

Answer (score 1):

It's actually unclear what technique he's talking about.  I suspect "scale" has a particular meaning in the context of weight lifting, which might make sense to his viewers but which does not mean anything to the rest of us.

If I were to guess, I would say it means to "adjust" the weight that you are lifting, so that you lift either progressively heavier or progressively lighter weights in a set.  See ["An Idiot's Guide to Progressive Strength Workouts"](https://breakingmuscle.com/fitness/an-idiots-guide-to-progressive-strength-workouts), if you're not familiar with the concept.

Either that, or to adjust the weight for the number of repetitions you are doing.  Again, it's not clear which he means, but it might make more sense if I watched the entire video.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, 'to scale' does not mean 'to climb'. It means 'to adjust appropriately.'